# Is deadlock necessarily true when the four conditions exist?

Tags: operating-system, deadlock

I understand the four necessary conditions, mutual exclusion, hold and wait, no preemption, and circular wait, for deadlock to occur. However, does there exist a situation where the four conditions are true and the system is not in a deadlock state?

In other words, if a deadlock occurs, there exist the four conditions. However, if there exist the four conditions, is there necessarily a deadlock? What is an example where the four conditions exist, and a system is not in a deadlock state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are *necessary* but not *sufficient* conditions, so there are almost certainly situations for which these conditions are true, but no deadlock occurs.

A system satisfying these conditions merely has deadlock states - there might be a path of execution that never reaches one of these deadlock states. I was struggling to synthesize an example, but thankfully [someone else did it for me](http://cs.nyu.edu/~gottlieb/courses/2000s/2006-07-fall/os2250/lectures/lecture-06.html).

Comment: Right, but what is a situation where the conditions are true, but no deadlock occurs?

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate whther there a deadlock by drawing a precedence graph and if there are cycles in the graph there will be a deadlock. You can also be unfortunate enough to get a livelock. If the graph has a cycle then the process can't be serialized. So to be certain about a process, draw its precedence graph and inspect whether the precedence graph contains cycles.